# CSS div has mind of its own - not obeying Float and Width values

Tags: css, wordpress, css-float

Float is not working, but I think it is because the main div has a mind of its own. The main div is correctly displaying background-color but it is not obeying the width value I set. #main seems to be displaying the same width as the parent div called #page-wrap

What could be the problem?

I've stripped down the code to figure out the root of the problem.

This is the only CSS in style.css

```
#page-wrap { overflow:hidden; width: 1100px; background: orange; }
/*Problem with #main is that it displays width: 1100px instead 300px*/
#main { float: left: width: 300px; background: red; } 
#sidebar { float: left; width: 250px; background: green; }
```

.

This is the only html in index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page-wrap">

<div id="main">
Hello
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/apple1.jpeg">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/apple2.jpeg">
</div>

</div></body></html>
```

.

Here is an image of this html/css in action

Notice the red incorrectly taking up 1100px instead of 300px

[image]

.

**Edit**

I've simplified the above by replacing the loop code with "hello" text

Resulting HTML when I click "view source"

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1/wp-content/themes/trying%20to%20fix%20sidebar%20home%20Balls%20of/style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body class="home blog logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support">
<div id="page-wrap">

<div id="main">
hello
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/wp-content/themes/trying%20to%20fix%20sidebar%20home%20Balls%20of/images/apples/apple1.jpeg">
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/wp-content/themes/trying%20to%20fix%20sidebar%20home%20Balls%20of/images/apples/apple2.jpeg">
</div>

</div></body></html>
```

Comment: "Float is not working, but I think it is because the container for the loop has a mind of its own." - you're funny!

Comment: What's the compiled HTML result of your loop?

Comment: You need to override the `mind: of-its-own;` property specification. I recommend the `mind: what-i-say;` property value.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're floating everything left?

Comment: torazaburo haha they need to make that a real property value and you're right too many floats so I removed the float:left from #page-wrap and added overflow:hidden; ----- @denisol see my edit for the compiled HTML

Comment: You didn't fix the type in `#main` yet.

Comment: torazaburo if you are referring to the last block of code, I've updated it

Comment: In `#main { float: left: width: 300px; background: red; }`, you have a colon, instead of a semi-colon, after `left`. That is the source of all your problems. You can fix that, then delete the question. :-)

Comment: torazaburo OMG! I am officially the stupidest person on earth. A freakin semicolon...oh god....I've spent hours and hours on this issue. Thanks for pointing out that I had a colon, the answer below pointed that out but I didn't realize that I used a colon by mistake

Comment: torazaburo it won't let me delete because it says "this questions has answers". can u help me delete the question? I don't think this question will benefit others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#contain-loop` needs a semi-colon after `float:left;`

```
#contain-loop { float: left; width: 300px; background: red; }
```

And if you're only floating elements to change their box display, I recommend you using `display: inline-block;` or `display: block;` instead of `float: left;` to avoid floating problems in the future.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9kb82md5/1/

Comment: Thanks denisol. The semi-colon solved the issue. I didn't realize that I was using a colon. I can't believe I pulled such a dumb mistake